# How to install Xcode 6?

Tags: macos, xcode, development, developer-program, swift

I just got myself a MBA and I am wondering how do I install Xcode 6 on my MBA?

In the Mac App Store I can see Xcode 5.1.1 so I have started installing that on the MBA. But, I want to install Xcode 6 and more specifically Swift. How do I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Xcode 6 currently requires an active [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/) or [Mac](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mac/) Developer Program membership, available from [developer.apple.com/programs](https://developer.apple.com/programs), as **Xcode 6 and Swift is not publicly available yet**.  Once Xcode 6 is out of beta / prerelease anyone should be able to download it from the MAS, but that is speculation based on past experience and not something Apple has announced.

Comment: Thanks a lot the quick response. I will go ahead and learn XC 5.1.1 for some time.

Comment: @thatmaheshrs if this answers your question please accept this answer by pressing the checkmark button just below the down vote button to the left of the answer.